# KnockoutJS - Rebinding ViewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to switch a object in a viewModel with an other, with the same type (e.g Person). If i do this:

```
var personViewModel = function (person) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = person.id;
  self.firstName = ko.observable(person.firstName);
  self.lastName = ko.observable(person.lastName);
  self.addresses = ko.observableArray(contact.addresses);

  self.removeAddress = function (address) {
  self.addresses.remove(address);
 }
}
```

and bind it with:

```
ko.applyBindings(new personViewModel(person), $("#person")[0]);
```

it works great on the first time, but if i bind it with a other object on a second time, the first binding will not disappear.

How can i switch easily the object person in my viewModel?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would basically want your entire view model to be observable, then swap in a new personViewModel object.  Would be like:

```
var viewModel = {
  person: ko.observable()
};

viewModel.person(new personViewModel(person));

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then, just swap a new person in like:

```
viewModel.person(new personViewModel(newPerson));
```

Comment: Great solution.  Very neat and simple.  I've been unhappy with using a global variable for the viewModel but had no idea how to get around it.  Thanks for this